# List all users in PostgreSQL and identify non ad user

Tags: postgresql

I wanted to list all users in postgreSQL and I would like to identify the users which are not linked to Active Directory.

select * from pg_user;

Above lists all users. I am trying to set up an alert when other dbas create an user which are not part of Active Directory and notify me.

I am looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your pg_hba.conf only had two lines, one for 'postgres' and one (which goes through AD) for every one else, then you would just need to monitor that file for changes. They might be able to create a user that doesn't yet exist in AD, but they would then be unable to log on.